# Should {accepted-answer} be a synonym of {accepting}?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, meta

Should [accepted-answer](/questions/tagged/accepted-answer) be a synonym of [accepting](/questions/tagged/accepting)?

I think that they are too similar too be told apart and, thus, should be synonyms. The only topic relating to accepting answers that is useful to keep apart from it seems to be accept rate (for which there is no tag).

If it matters, [they are synonyms on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/accepted-answer/synonyms).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Comment: It is a synonym now.